# Define ParameterizableViewController to auto redirect path url with view

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using spring boot 1.2.1 and I would like to configure a ParameterizableViewController like I was doing in xml style :

for example before I was doing :

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/ie7"/>
```

That code redirects an url like http://mywebsite.com/mycontext/ie7 to a jsp placed in /WEB-INF/views/ie7.jsp without creating a controller directly.

I would like to do the same thing with spring boot. After checking on the net I had this in my config file :

```
@Bean(name = "ie7Controller")
public ParameterizableViewController getIe7ControllerView() {
    ParameterizableViewController viewController = new ParameterizableViewController();
    viewController.setViewName("ie7");
    return viewController;
}
```

In my application.properties I configure the view like this :

```
spring.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.view.suffix=.jsp
```

I try to add also :

```
 @Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}
```

But when I try http://mywebsite.com/mycontext/ie7 I got a 404.
Here is the logs I got :

During app launch :

```
Rejected bean name 'ie7Controller': no URL paths identified
```

When I try to call the page :

```
2015-02-11 09:01:42.693 DEBUG 1160 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]      o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name    'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/stdapps/ie7]
2015-02-11 09:01:42.699 DEBUG 1160 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /ie7
2015-02-11 09:01:42.704 DEBUG 1160 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/ie7]
2015-02-11 09:01:42.706 DEBUG 1160 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/ie7] are [/**]
2015-02-11 09:01:42.708 DEBUG 1160 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/ie7] are {}
2015-02-11 09:01:42.712 DEBUG 1160 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/ie7] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@39689892]]] and 1 interceptor
2015-02-11 09:01:42.714 DEBUG 1160 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/stdapps/ie7] is: -1
```

do I miss something ? I feel like I need to specify and url somewhere, I try to add @RequestMapping(value="ie7") with @Bean(name = "ie7Controller") with no luck

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly then the following code should do the trick:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/ie7").setViewName("ie7");
    };

}
```